# Derivative of Associated Legendre polynomials at $x = \pm 1$

Tags: computational-mathematics, spherical-harmonics

I'm creating meshes for spherical harmonics, and I need a normal at a given point. Whenever I'm at the poles, $\cos{\theta} = \pm 1$, and I do not know how to find the derivative there. All the formulas I have found to describe the derivative have an $1 - x^2$ in the denominator, and I get an indeterminate form. For reference, the one I'm using is:
$$(P_\ell^m)^\prime(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2} P_\ell^{m+1}(x) + mx P_\ell^m (x)}{x^2 - 1}$$

I found the derivatives for some cases, and it seems that $m = \pm 1$ results in $\pm \infty$, $m = 0$ yields triangular numbers, and $|m| \ge 3$ makes the derivative $0$. But I can't find an overarching pattern or algorithm I can use to produce these. Is there a nice way?

Comment: Are you interested in the case of non-negative integer $\ell$ and $-\ell \leqslant m \leqslant \ell$?

Comment: Yeah, $\ell$ and $m$ just integers, and $|m| \le \ell$. Hard to do fractional parameters on paper, I can't imagine it in code.

Comment: This section in the NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions might be relevant: http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.8 .

Comment: i only know a tiny bit of numerical analysis, but your quotient should have a limit at $x = \pm 1$.  Is it possible to extend the time on the bounty?

Comment: What does it mean to write a mesh for spherical harmonics, what are the criteria?

Comment: @johnmangual Probably? I'll go figure out how to do that. And the mesh is a set of triangles that approximate the surface (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_mesh). My sample points for $\phi$ are evenly spaced in $[0, 2\pi]$, and $\theta$ is spaced proportional to its sine in $[0, \pi]$. It's the endpoints of $\theta$ that give me trouble.

Comment: @Yury I'm having a bit of trouble understanding their notation. If I'm looking for the associated Legendre polynomial that's used to define the spherical harmonics, that's italicized $P$ with a subscript $\nu$ and superscript $\mu$, and I should use 14.8.8, I think?

Comment: Are you interested in $x\in (-1,1)$ (i.e. you want to compute the left derivative at $x=1$ or the right derivative at $x=-1$)? Then you should apply 14.8.2 as long as $l\notin\{-m,\dots, m-1\}$. Functions $\mathrm{P}$ and $P$ are defined on $(-1,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, respectively.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in that. But I thought $P$ was the one defined on $(-1, 1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularity at the denominator can be eliminated using L'Hospital's theorem, once you notice that the associated Legendre function has value of $0$ at $\pm 1$.

---

Maybe this is not a right solution, because I found another formula about the derivative of the associated Legendre function here,

- [Spherical Harmonics](https://web.archive.org/web/20070412093658/http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/SphericalHarmonics.pdf)

and it gives a difference solution when I apply the same method.

Comment: Oh man, Calc I to the rescue. I didn't see that coming at all! I'm not really working on the project anymore, but I'll write something up for the next programmer. Thanks!

I had a bounty on this earlier, so it's only fair that you get it now. (I think that's how they work?)

Comment: Could you please elaborate to make this into a full answer? Furthermore, see the [editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on how to format your answer.

Comment: Oh, I can't award it until 24 hours pass. Huh. And I know it's not a complete answer, but I'm quite grateful that he somehow dug this up from half a year ago and answered. More details would obviously be great, but it's just a matter of using L'Hopital and isolating the $(P_\ell^m)'(x)$ that shows up, I think.

Comment: Wait, there's a $(P_\ell^{m+1})'(x)$ term I can't seem to kill in every case. Any advice?

Comment: Okay, so user116561 was right, using L'Hopital and noting that $P_\ell^m(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $\pm 1$ is enough to nail most of the cases ($m \ge 3$). For $0$ and $2$, it's still L'Hopital, and for $m = 1$ I feel it also works there.

Comment: What's the policy for bounties here? He gave me exactly the tools to solve it, for a problem several months old, but he says he doesn't want it because it's not a full solution.

Comment: Whatever, it's gotta go somewhere, right? :D Thanks for the hint/answer/appropriate-tool-to-use!

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using the formula from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Definition_for_non-negative_integer_parameters_.E2.84.93_and_m) ?

\[  P_m^l (x) = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^\ell \ell!} (1-x^2)^{m/2} \frac{d^{\ell + m}}{dx^{\ell + m}}(1 - x^2)^{\ell} \]

Let $y = 1-x \approx 0$,

\[  P_m^l (y) = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^\ell \ell!} y^{m/2}(2-y)^{m/2} \frac{d^{\ell + m}}{dy^{\ell + m}} y^{\ell}(2-y)^\ell \propto y^{m/2} \approx 0\]

I am guessing the derivative is always zero unless $m = 0$, the only interesting case.

---

Or plug in $x = \cos \theta$ and take the limit $\theta \to 0$:

\[  (P_\ell^m)^\prime(\cos \theta) = \frac{\sin \theta \, P_\ell^{m+1}(\cos \theta) + m \cos \theta \,  P_\ell^m (\cos \theta )}{\sin^2 \theta} \]

Not sure how to evaluate this... [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) are rotationally symmetric, so maybe they shouldn't have non-zero derivatives at the poles?

Comment: It becomes infinite for many of them when $m \ne 0$. For example: $P_\ell^m(x) = -\sqrt{1 - x^2}$, the derivative of which is $+\infty$ at 1 and $-\infty$ at -1.

Comment: As for the second part: The normal definitely exists for some of them (m = 0) and some others. So is it that the cross product formula for the normal breaks down? $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by user116561, L'Hopital and induction is the way to go. Gotta break it into cases though. And I have to apply it to a different recurrence relation, one that fixes $m$:

$$( P_\ell^m)'(x) = \frac{(\ell + 1 - m) P_{\ell+1}^m(x) - (\ell + 1)xP_\ell^m(x)}{x^2 - 1}$$

which gives:

$$\lim_{x \to c}~( P_\ell^m)'(x) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{(\ell + 1 - m) (P_{\ell+1}^m)'(x) - (\ell + 1)(P_\ell^m(x) + x(P_\ell^m)'(x))}{2x}$$

when L'Hopital is applicable, of course. But it is applicable for all $\ell,m$, when $c = 1$.

When $m = 0$, one can check $P_\ell^0(1) = 1$ for all $\ell$. So the numerator is $(\ell + 1) 1 - (\ell + 1) 1$, which is $0$. When $m \ne 0$, then $P_\ell^0(1) = 0$ for all $\ell$. So then the numerator obviously goes to $0$.

---

$m = 0 : \frac{\ell(\ell + 1)}{2}$

---

Base: $P_0^0(x) = 1$, so its derivative is $0$ everywhere. In particular it is $\frac{0\cdot 1}{2} = 0$ at $1$.

Assume $\lim_{x \to 1}( P_\ell^0 )'(x) = \frac{\ell(\ell + 1)}{2}$ for some $\ell$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1}~( P_\ell^0)'(x) &= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(\ell + 1) (P_{\ell+1}^0)'(x) - (\ell + 1)(P_\ell^0(x) + x(P_\ell^0)'(x))}{2x} \\
\frac{\ell(\ell + 1)}{2} &= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ell + 1}{2} \left( (P_{\ell+1}^0)'(x) - P_\ell^0(x) - x(P_\ell^0)'(x) \right) \\
\ell &= \left[ \lim_{x \to 1} (P_{\ell+1}^0)'(x) \right] - 1 - \frac{\ell(\ell + 1)}{2} \\
\lim_{x \to 1} (P_{\ell+1}^0)'(x) &= \ell + 1 + \frac{\ell(\ell + 1)}{2} = \frac{(\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{2} \\
\end{align*}
$$

So $\lim_{x \to 1}( P_\ell^0 )'(x) = \frac{\ell(\ell + 1)}{2}$ for all $\ell$.

---

$m = 1 : \infty$

---

What do? I can't throw infinities about willy-nilly, because limit laws don't work as nicely and I can't "subtract infinity from both sides".

---

$m = 2 : -\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4}$

---

Base: $P_2^2(x) = 3(1 - x^2)$. The derivative is continuous, and at $1$ it is $-6$, which is $-\frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4}{4}$.

Assume: $\lim_{x \to 1}( P_\ell^2 )'(x) = -\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4}$ for some $\ell$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1}~( P_\ell^2)'(x) &= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(\ell - 1) (P_{\ell+1}^2)'(x) - (\ell + 1)(P_\ell^2(x) + x(P_\ell^2)'(x))}{2x} \\
-\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4} &= \frac{(\ell - 1) \left[ \lim_{x \to 1}  (P_{\ell+1}^2)'(x) \right] - (\ell + 1) \left(0 + -\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4} \right)}{2} \\
2 \left( - \frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4} \right) &= (\ell - 1) \left[ \lim_{x \to 1}  (P_{\ell+1}^2)'(x) \right] - (\ell + 1) \left(-\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4} \right) \\
-\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4} (2 + (\ell + 1)) &= (\ell - 1) \left[ \lim_{x \to 1}  (P_{\ell+1}^2)'(x) \right] \\
-\frac{\ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)(\ell + 3)}{4} &= \left[ \lim_{x \to 1}  (P_{\ell+1}^2)'(x) \right]
\end{align*}
$$

So $\lim_{x \to 1}( P_\ell^2 )'(x) = -\frac{(\ell - 1) \ell (\ell + 1)(\ell + 2)}{4}$ for all $\ell$.

---

$m \ge 3 : 0$

---

Base: can't prove it, but $P_\ell^m(1) = 0$ for all $\ell \ge m \ge 3$.

Assume: $\lim_{x \to 1}( P_\ell^m )'(x) = 0$ for all $m \ge 3$ and some $\ell \ge m$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1}~( P_\ell^m)'(x) &= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(\ell + 1 - m) (P_{\ell+1}^m)'(x) - (\ell + 1)(P_\ell^m(x) + x(P_\ell^m)'(x))}{2x} \\
0 &= \frac{(\ell + 1 - m) \left[ \lim_{x \to 1} (P_{\ell+1}^m)'(x) \right] - (\ell + 1)(0 + 0)}{2} \\
0 &= (\ell + 1 - m) \left[ \lim_{x \to 1} (P_{\ell+1}^m)'(x) \right] \\
\ell \ge m &\implies (\ell + 1 - m) \ne 0 \\
0 &= \lim_{x \to 1} (P_{\ell+1}^m)'(x)
\end{align*}
$$

So for all $\ell \ge m \ge 3$: $\lim_{x \to 1}( P_\ell^m )'(x) = 0$.

---

What I'm still stuck on:

- The recursive step of $m = 1$.
- The base case of $m \ge 3$.

Everything else can be found using $P_\ell^m(-x) = (-1)^{\ell + m} P_\ell^m(x)$ and $P_\ell^{-m}(x) = (-1)^m \frac{(\ell - m)!}{(\ell + m)!} P_\ell^m(x)$.